# Azure AD B2C - Pass current culture to REST API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I'm working on a REST API that sends a confirmation email for a custom policy. Can anyone tell me if there is a way to pass the current culture so I can send a localized email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an `<InputClaim />` to the REST API technical profile for passing the current culture as follows:

```
<InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="mkt" PartnerClaimType="mkt" DefaultValue="{Culture:RFC5646}" />
```

where "mkt" (market) is an example of a claim type that you can replace with your own one.

"{Culture:RFC5646}" is known as a claims resolver.

Be sure to add the claim type to the TrustFrameworkPolicy/BuildingBlocks/ClaimsSchema section.